# Tooltip is not displayed when using annotation in ChartJs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

When a user try to hover on a dot, it only displays a blue line but it does not show a tooltip as a result below

**lib version:** 
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7"

Actual : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USbEz.png) 
Expected: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjLgQ.png) 
 
 In chart configuration

```
 export chart = () => {
         data:{ ... }, 
         options: {
             tooltips: {
              displayColors: false,
              mode: 'index', intersect: true,
              callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                  return `${data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label}(${Math.round(tooltipItem.xLabel * 100) / 100
                    },${Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100})`;
                },
              },
            },
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
            annotation: {
              drawTime: "afterDatasetsDraw",
              events: ["mouseover"],
              annotations: [],
            },
        }
    }
```

convertToHoverLine();

```
export const convertToHoverLine = (value, scaleID) => {
  return {
    key: "hoverLine",
    type: "line",
    mode: "vertical",
    scaleID,
    value,
    borderColor: "blue",
    onMouseout: null,
    onMouseover: null,
  }
}
```

handleHoverChart(); => this function will trigger when a user hover a dot on the chart

```
   export const handleHoverChart = (myChart, x, scaleID) => {
         const indexLine = myChart.options.annotation.annotations.findIndex(i => i.key === "hoverLine")
         if (indexLine === -1) {
            myChart.options.annotation.annotations.push(convertToHoverLine(x,scaleID))
         } else {
           myChart.options.annotation.annotations[indexLine] = convertToHoverLine(x,scaleID);
           }
  myChart.update()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by move chart update into the condition

```
export const handleHoverChart = (myChart, x, scaleID) => {
       const indexLine = myChart.options.annotation.annotations.findIndex(i => i.key === "hoverLine")
       if(indexLine === -1){   
           myChart.options.annotation.annotations.push(convertToHoverLine(x,scaleID))
           myChart.update()
        }else{
              myChart.options.annotation.annotations[indexLine] = convertToHoverLine(x,scaleID);
             }
 }
```